# Generalize the use of numpy.meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy

Below, a minimal example that produce an expanded grid using the `meshgrid` function:

```
from numpy import array, meshgrid

foo = array(([1, 2, 3], [4, 5]))
array(meshgrid(foo[0], foo[1])).T.reshape(-1, 2)

##  array([[1, 4],
##         [1, 5],
##         [2, 4],
##         [2, 5],
##         [3, 4],
##         [3, 5]])
```

I'd like to implement the same, but I don't want to hard code the shape of `foo`.

Here is a second minimal example with a different shape for `foo`:

```
from numpy import array, meshgrid

foo = array(([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]))
array(meshgrid(foo[0], foo[1], foo[2])).T.reshape(-1, 3)

##  array([[1, 4, 6],
##         [1, 5, 6],
##         [2, 4, 6],
##         [2, 5, 6],
##         [3, 4, 6],
##         [3, 5, 6],
##         [1, 4, 7],
##         [1, 5, 7],
##         [2, 4, 7],
##         [2, 5, 7],
##         [3, 4, 7],
##         [3, 5, 7]])
```

As one could easily see, the only changes I made are:

- Add `foo[2]` as argument to the `meshgrid` function;
- Change the `reshape` arguments from `(-1, 2)` to `(-1, 3)`.

Can someone help me generalize my solution so I can use the same expression in both cases instead of having to make the described changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can transform your call to have it working for any 2D input:

```py
from numpy import array, meshgrid

def mesh(foo):
  return array(meshgrid(*foo)).T.reshape(-1, foo.shape[0])

print(mesh(array(([1, 2, 3], [4, 5]))))
print(mesh(array(([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]))))
```

Comment: Thanks! I still struggle with the use of `*args`, sorry for the very basic question!

Comment: No problem with that, it's a bit hard at the beginning as `*args` really has two different (inverse) meanings depending on the context. This ambivalence makes the unary `*` operator a bit confusing at start. In a function signature that can be interpreted as "merge all the parameters in a tuple named `args`" while in a function call (like in this case) it can be interpreted as "expand `foo` to several arguments". These are usually respectively referred as _packing_ vs. _unpacking_. In other words `def f(*X)` with `f(*(1, 2, 3))` works the exact same way as `def f(X)`  with `f((1, 2, 3))`.

Comment: Except that in the first case we _packed_ then _unpacked_ the tuple `(1, 2, 3)` while in the second case we passed `(1, 2, 3)` directly. In the end, `X` has the same value inside both `f` functions.